# Creating a pattern using Python Graphics Module

Tags: python, graphics, zelle-graphics

I'm trying to draw a specific pattern in a 100x100 window using the John Zelle’s graphics module, however I'm struggling to reach the intended pattern. I am sure of the increments and the range, in fact I get the first column right however the the others are stuck together and I can’t find what I did wrong. Any thoughts?
Here is the code:

```
def pattern1():
    win = GraphWin("Rec",100,100)
    x=0
    y=10
    x2=20
    y2=10
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(3):
            r = Rectangle(Point(x,1), Point(y,100))
            r.setFill("Red")
            r.setOutline("Red")
            r.draw(win)
            r2 = Rectangle(Point(1,x2), Point(100,y2))
            y=y+10
            x2=x2+20
        x=0
        x=x+20
        y2=y2+20
```

This is the pattern I'm trying to do:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/WZsVeVl]

Comment: Try to go step by step through the program and explain for yourself what every line does. It also helps to add comments and show them here. This way, we can tell you where your approach goes off. A few places to start: `x=0` `x=x+20` simply sets `x` to `20` - is this desired? You never use `r2`. `r` always starts at y-coordinate `1` and ends at y-coordinate `100`. And you are using `y` in a points x-coordinate. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I see two separated parts which need separated `for`-loops: vertical lines and horizontal lines.

```
from graphics import *

def pattern():
    win = GraphWin("Rec", 100, 100)

    # vertical lines
    for x in range(0, 100, 40):
        r = Rectangle(Point(x, 0), Point(x+20, 100))
        r.setFill("Red")
        r.setOutline("Red")
        r.draw(win)

    # horizontal lines
    for y in range(20, 100, 40):
        r = Rectangle(Point(0, y), Point(100, y+20))
        r.setFill("Red")  # "Green"
        r.setOutline("Red")  # "Green"
        r.draw(win)

pattern()
```

Using different colors then you can see

[image]

If you draw first horizontal lines then you can see

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it's easier to draw what isn't there than what is:

```
from graphics import *

def pattern():
    for y in range(0, 100, 40):
        for x in range(20, 100, 40):
            r = Rectangle(Point(x, y), Point(x+20, y+20))
            r.setFill("White")
            r.setOutline("White")
            r.draw(win)

win = GraphWin("Rec", 100, 100)
win.setBackground('Red')

pattern()
```

[image]